# High impedance opamp attenuator

Tags: operational-amplifier

Is it possible to design a single-op-amp schematic to attenuate a high impedance signal? The designs that I know have these limitations:

- Non-inverting with input directly going into op-amp, has gain ≥1
- Inverting op-amp draws current from the input.

The input is a pressure sensor (probably Wheatstone bridge based) but the impedance is in the area of 100kΩ.

The output goes into a low-pass filter (out of my control) which has non-negligible impedance, and ADC, so it needs to be driven hard.

If possible I don't want to use a voltage follower to buffer the signal. My feeling says it should be possible with one op-amp but I can't think of a way, and searching led me to nothing. Inverted-ness doesn't matter.

[Edit]

The resistance of the filter measures 5.1kΩ at DC. The bandwidth is non-existant (pressure changes take multiple seconds). Accuracy is not important as long as it's repeatable, the min and max are defined, and the domain is monotonic. Input min/max ~2V-12V. Output min/max ~1V-5V. Opamp is rail-to-rail, single-rail powered with 0V/12V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flaw7T.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You shouldn't have a problem attenuating it with a resistive voltage divider. No point in overcomplicating things, right? Then just use your op amp as a voltage-follower/buffer after the divider.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a voltage follower?  You could make a negative gain to attenuate, but that requires an opamp and 2 resistor, but so does a voltage follower and a resistive divider. It is pretty common to use a voltage follower followed by a resistive divider.

Comment: Underconstrained - put some numbers on things like bandwidth, attenuation, input impedance of low pass filter, accuracy required etc...

Comment: Draw a schematic of what you think you need, explain what it needs to do. State the reasons **why** an opamp is needed. You're already thinking in solutions while you have not even fully described (the constraints) of your problem yet. Don't make presumptions like *high impedance* and that because of that you need a certain circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it's no problem at all if the output signal you want to feed into the low pass filter has some non-zero impedance. It's just important to know *what* impedance it has.

Therefor you can use a voltage divider after a voltage follower (upper subcircuit).

It's [Thévenin equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9venin%27s_theorem) (lower subcircuit) is a voltage source \$v_{th} = v_{in} \frac{R2}{R1+R2}\$ with series resistance \$R_{th} = R_1 || R_2\$.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZy1XH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>